# Android - Failing to load gif file using Movie class

Tags: android, gif, android-sdcard

I'm trying to use `android.graphics.Movie` to play a GIF file from `/sdcard/download`.

If I put the file in the `drawable` folder in the APK, I can load it using:

```
InputStream istr = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.animfile);
Movie movie = Movie.decodeStream(istr);
```

That works. `movie.duration()` will show the correct duration, which I use to derive the value for `movie.setTime()`.

The problem happens if, instead of drawable, I try to load it from the sd-card using

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/animfile.gif";
Movie movie = Movie.decodeFile(path);
```

It seems to load *something* as `movie` isn't null. But the problem is that `movie.duration()` returns `0`.

Any idea why this happens, and what I should be doing?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this as well.  After much trial and error I got it to work using getContentResolver().openInputStream and the dead streamToBytes code in the android [BitmapDecode example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/BitmapDecode.html), which seems to work.  I haven't come across an explanation yet as to why this needs to be done differently for package resources and sd files.

example:

```
...
Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
java.io.InputStream is;
try {
    is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
}
catch(Exception e) {
}
byte[] array = streamToBytes(is);
Movie movie = Movie.decodeByteArray(array, 0, array.length);


private static byte[] streamToBytes(InputStream is) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    try {
        while ((len = is.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
    }
    return os.toByteArray();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are right, except a one. You shouldn't use Uri and ContentResolver. Short solution is that you should use

```
Movie.decodeByteArray(array, 0, array.length)
```

instead of

```
Movie.decodeFile(path);
```

clue is in reset() method implementation of some stream that created inside the decodeFile(path) method.

Answer (score 1):

```
 is = new FileInputStream(file path);



                if (path != null) {
                            try {
                                byte[] array = streamToBytes(is);
                                mMovie =  Movie.decodeByteArray(array, 0, array.length);

                                mDuration = mMovie.duration();
                                Log.v("total time ", mDuration + "");
                            } finally {
                                is.close();
                            }
                        } else {
                            throw new IOException("Unable to open R.raw.");
                        }


 private byte[] streamToBytes(InputStream is) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                try {
                    while ((len = is.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
                        os.write(buffer, 0, len);
                    }
                } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                }
                return os.toByteArray();
            }
```